# Java method is skipping two numbers when auto assigning the ID.

Tags: javafx-8

Here is my add product method that is skipping two numbers every time it 
auto assigns a new ID when it saves the new product. I have changed this 
method numerous times to no avail. Any suggestions would be a great help.

```
@FXML
private void goSaveNewProduct(ActionEvent event) {
    Products newProduct = new Products();
    Boolean save = false;
    Double newProductCost = Double.parseDouble(priceTextField.getText());
    Double newTotal = product.getPartsTotal();

if (isAddProductValid()){
   newProduct.setProductName(productNameTextField.getText());            
   newProduct.setProductInStock(Integer.parseInt(invTextField.getText()));         
   newProduct.setProductPrice(Double.parseDouble(priceTextField.getText()));            
   newProduct.setProductMaximum(Integer.parseInt(maxTextField.getText()));            
   newProduct.setProductMinimum(Integer.parseInt(minTextField.getText()));
   newProduct.setAssociatedParts(associatedPartsTable.getItems());
    }    
    if (Objects.equals(newTotal, newProductCost)) {
        save = true;
        mainApp.getProductsData().add(newProduct);
        addProductsStage.close();  
    }
    else {                  
        // Warn user product price is not correct.
        Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
        alert.initOwner(mainApp.getPrimaryStage());
        alert.setTitle("Product Price Warning");
        alert.setHeaderText("Please Correct Product Price!");
        alert.setContentText("Product price must equal the cost of parts!");
        Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();
        if (result.get() == ButtonType.OK){
        // ... user chose OK
        save = false;
         } else {
        // ... user chose CANCEL or closed the dialog
        }
    }    
}
```

And here is my product constructor with the static ID counter.

```
public Products(String productName, Integer productInStock, Double 
productPrice, Integer productMax, 
    Integer productMin) {
    mainApp.productsIdCounter = mainApp.productsIdCounter +1;    
    this.productID = new SimpleIntegerProperty(mainApp.productsIdCounter);
    this.productName = new SimpleStringProperty(productName);
    this.productInStock = new SimpleIntegerProperty(productInStock);
    this.productPrice = new SimpleDoubleProperty(productPrice);
    this.productMax = new SimpleIntegerProperty(productMax);
    this.productMin = new SimpleIntegerProperty(productMin);
    this.associatedParts = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
}
```

And here is my method that gets the total of the parts:

```
// returns the total of all parts price.
public Double getPartsTotal() {
    double result = 0.0;
    if(associatedParts != null) {
    for(int i = 0 ; i < associatedParts.size(); i++) {
    result += associatedParts.get(i).getPartPrice();
    }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Show us the `Products` constructor you're actually using.

Comment: Figured out the problem.  I inadvertently had two product constructors in the  add products file.  LOL.  Dummy me.  Sorry I posted the wrong consturctor first time.  This is the constuctor I should have posted.  public Products(String productName, Integer productInStock, Double productPrice, ObservableList associatedParts) .